# How do I print a dictionary so my items are printed in quotation marks and in brackets?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to print my dictionary in quotes and in brackets.

my output is this:

I1: A1, T1
I2: A2, T2
I3: A3, T3

but i want this:

I1: ('A1', 'T1')
I2: ('A2', 'T2')
I3: ('A3', 'T3')

This is my code.....

```
def isbn_dictionary(filename):

    isbn_dic={}
    for line in open(filename,"r"):
        author,title,isbn = line.strip().split(',')
        isbn_dic[isbn] = author + ", " + title
print (isbn_dic)
```

Comment: f-strings make printing easier: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this input as a list (just to be easier to show here)

```py
input = [
    'A1, T11, I1',
    'A1, T12, I2',
    'A2, T21, I3',
    'A3, T31, I4',
]

def isbn_dictionary(input):
    isbn_dic={}
    for line in input:
        author, title, isbn = line.strip().split(',')
        isbn_dic[isbn] = f"({author}, {title})"
    return isbn_dic

test = isbn_dictionary(input)

print(test)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Valerie. I thought of this too. I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of doing it. It passed the checks I needed so it will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Storing the result as a tuple like this gets you a very similar result and lets you keep the single quotes for the strings instead of manually formatting them

```
isbn_dic[isbn] = author, title
```

For example

```
>>> temp = {}
>>> temp['test'] = '1', '2'
>>> temp['test2'] = '1', '2'
>>> print(temp)
{'test': ('1', '2'), 'test2': ('1', '2')
```

or if you don't want the braces and want it exactly like your sample output, you can use the items() method and f-strings

```
>>> test = {}
>>> test['test'] = '1', '2'
>>> test['test2'] = '1', '2'
>>> print(' '.join(f"{k}: {v}" for k, v in test.items()))
test: ('1', '2') test2: ('1', '2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `F-Strings`

```
def isbn_dictionary(filename):

    isbn_dic = {}
    for line in open(filename, "r"):
        author, title, isbn = line.strip().split(',')
        isbn_dic[isbn] = f"('{author}','{title}')"


print(isbn_dic)
```